# PHP function to check for a id

Tags: php

I have a sql query that look like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT weight, added_date, etid 
        FROM balance_events 
        WHERE added_date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' 
        AND '".$to_date."' 
        ORDER BY `balance_events`.`added_date` ASC";
```

After some operations I got a object that looks like this:

```
array(34) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#55 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(4) "5520"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:22"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#56 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "16860"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:24"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#57 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "17040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:25"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#58 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "16460"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:26"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#59 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "16280"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:27"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#60 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "40200"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:29"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#61 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42120"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:31"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#62 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:33"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [8]=>
  object(stdClass)#63 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:48"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [9]=>
  object(stdClass)#64 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:49"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [10]=>
  object(stdClass)#65 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:51:50"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [11]=>
  object(stdClass)#66 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:23"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [12]=>
  object(stdClass)#67 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:24"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [13]=>
  object(stdClass)#68 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42100"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:26"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [14]=>
  object(stdClass)#69 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:27"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [15]=>
  object(stdClass)#70 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:45"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [16]=>
  object(stdClass)#71 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:49"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [17]=>
  object(stdClass)#72 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42080"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:50"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [18]=>
  object(stdClass)#73 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:52:51"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [19]=>
  object(stdClass)#74 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:54:14"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [20]=>
  object(stdClass)#75 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:57:05"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [21]=>
  object(stdClass)#76 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 12:57:47"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [22]=>
  object(stdClass)#77 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42060"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:02:19"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [23]=>
  object(stdClass)#78 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42120"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:02:48"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [24]=>
  object(stdClass)#79 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42140"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:02:51"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [25]=>
  object(stdClass)#80 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42160"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:02:55"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [26]=>
  object(stdClass)#81 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42140"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:02:58"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [27]=>
  object(stdClass)#82 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "42240"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:00"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [28]=>
  object(stdClass)#83 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "41800"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:02"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [29]=>
  object(stdClass)#84 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "30340"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:04"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [30]=>
  object(stdClass)#85 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "25780"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:05"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [31]=>
  object(stdClass)#86 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "24980"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:06"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [32]=>
  object(stdClass)#87 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(5) "26380"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:07"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [33]=>
  object(stdClass)#88 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-01 13:03:12"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Now at this point I want to test if on that interval there is a etid with the value of 4 or 5 ( and there is one at 2016-08-01 13:02:19), in that case I want to ignore this interval and go to the next one.

This is how my function looks like:

```
private function _checketid($list){
         foreach($list as $row){
            if ($row->etid == 4 or $row->etid ==5){
                 return False;
             }
            return True;
         }
       }
```

And this is how I call it:

```
if ($this->_checketid($newinterval) != False){
        $finallist[]= $this->_maxvalueinterval($newinterval);
                    }
```

But that list finallist will append evan if the etid is 4 or 5 on some point in the interval. What is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add `return true` inside the loop so the loop runs only once...
Move that `return true` outside the loop to let the loop run ;)

```
private function _checketid($list){
         foreach($list as $row){
            if ($row->etid == 4 or $row->etid ==5){
                 return False;
             }

         }
         return True;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, that was it! All due respect!